# Calling C++ dll from renderer process using node ffi-napi electron

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron

I am creating a windows application using electron. I want to call C++ .dll method using ffi-napi. for that, I have written the below code(sharing C++ and electron code). I have stuck on the "Passing_Dll.js" file which is not updating the label with id ="GenName" on click of start and stop button. I mean ces.start() or ces.stop() function is not working in "Passing_Dll.js" file. I tried to put this line document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = "Dummy string" after line var ffi =require("ffi-napi") in "Passing_Dll.js" file and realize it is not displaying even dummy string also in GUI. but if I put same line document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = "Dummy string" in start and stop function in "Passing_Dll.js" file before ces.start(() and ces.stop() then it is displaying the "Dummy string". Can somebody suggest to me what I am doing wrong? why it is not executing "Passing_Dll.js" correctly. do we need to do something with main.js or something with package.json files. please suggest. it would be much apricated if you can send some a working code snippet.

**dll.h**

```
#ifdef DLL1_EXPORTS
#define DLL1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

enum GUIENUM
{
    START = 0,
    STOP,
    DEBUG,
    STATUS,
};

typedef bool(*Callback)(bool, const char*);
extern "C" DLL1_API BOOL Connect(const char *userName, const char *password, Callback callback);

typedef void(*callbackMethod)(int statustype, const char* status);
extern "C" DLL1_API void GetCallMethod(callbackMethod callback);

extern "C" DLL1_API void Start();
extern "C" DLL1_API void Stop();
```

**dll.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "Dll1.h"
callbackMethod m_callback;

// This is an example of an exported variable
DLL1_API BOOL Connect(const char *userName, const char *password, Callback callback)
{
    callback(true, "User is connected");

    return true;
}

DLL1_API void GetCallMethod(callbackMethod callback)
{
    m_callback = callback;
    m_callback(START, "Initializaition is done");
}

DLL1_API void Start()
{
    m_callback(STATUS, "Start is pressed");
}

DLL1_API void Stop()
{
    m_callback(DEBUG, "stop is pressed");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>SIMS_R 5.2.10.2 GEN1.2 -AppFLR</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <label for="name" id ="GenName">R 16_31_80D7_99</label><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="startFunction()" value="Display" >Start</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopFunction()" value="Display2">Stop</button><br>   
    <script src="Passing_Dll.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**main.js**

```
const{BrowserWindow} =require("electron");
const app=require('electron').app;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:600, height: 650});
  
   // Disable menu
   mainWindow.setMenu(null)
    
   // and load the index.html of the app.
   mainWindow.loadURL('file://'+__dirname+'/index.html')
}
app.on('ready',createWindow);
```

**Passing_Dll.js**

```
var ffi =require("ffi-napi");
var ref =require("ref-napi");
var Enum = require('enum')
var constString = ref.types.CString;
var bool = ref.types.bool;
var int = ref.types.int;
var enumCallback = new Enum({  'START': 0,
  'STOP': 1,
  'DEBUG': 2,
  'STATUS': 3
}); 

var callback = ffi.Callback(bool, [bool, constString], function (sec, data) {
    console.log(sec)
    console.log(data);
  
  });

var callback2 =ffi.Callback(ref.types.void, [int, constString], function (sec, data) {
    switch(sec)
    {
      case enumCallback.START.value: 
       console.log(sec);
       console.log(data);
       document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = data;
       break;
       case enumCallback.STOP.value: 
       console.log(sec);
       console.log(data);
       document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = data;
       break;
       case enumCallback.STATUS.value: 
       console.log(sec);
       console.log(data);
       document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = data;
       break;
       case enumCallback.DEBUG.value: 
       console.log(sec);
       console.log(data);
       document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = data
       break;
       default:
        console.log(sec);
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = data
        break;
    }
});

var libloc = "./Dll1.dll";
  
const ces = ffi.Library(libloc, {
  'Connect': [bool, [constString, constString, 'pointer']],
  'GetCallMethod':[ref.types.void, ['pointer']],
  'Start': [ref.types.void,[ ]],
  'Stop': [ref.types.void,[ ]],
  
});

module.exports = ces;

var maxLength = 200;
var nameBuffer1 = Buffer.alloc(maxLength);
nameBuffer1.fill(0); 
nameBuffer1.write("user", 0, "utf-8"); 


var nameBuffer2 = Buffer.alloc(maxLength);
nameBuffer2.fill(0); 
nameBuffer2.write("password", 0, "utf-8");

ces.Connect(nameBuffer1,nameBuffer2,callback)
ces.GetCallMethod(callback2)
  
function startFunction()
{
    ces.Start()
}
  
function stopFunction()
{
    ces.Stop()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The render process in electron doesn't have access to your native libraries, so you cannot call the native functions directly from the js linked in index.html. Instead, you need to use the ipc provided by electron to invoke the native function, and pass the data returned from the native function to the renderer process.

**ipc.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

// send message to main process to run start function
function startFunction() {
  ipcRenderer.send("start")
}

function stopFunction() {
  ipcRenderer.send("stop")
}

ipcRenderer.on("callback-data", function(e, data) {
  document.getElementById('GenName').innerHTML = data;
})
```

**main.js**

```
const{BrowserWindow, ipcMain} =require("electron");
const app=require('electron').app;
const {ces, startFunction} = require("./Passing_Dll")

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:600, height: 650});
  
   // Disable menu
   mainWindow.setMenu(null)
    
   // and load the index.html of the app.
   mainWindow.loadURL('file://'+__dirname+'/index.html')
}
app.on('ready',createWindow);

ipcMain.on("start", function (e) {
  startFunction(e)
})

ipcMain.on("stop", function (e) {
  ces.Stop()
})
```

**Passing_Dll.js**

```
var ffi =require("ffi-napi");
var ref =require("ref-napi");
var Enum = require('enum')
var constString = ref.types.CString;
var bool = ref.types.bool;
var int = ref.types.int;
var enumCallback = new Enum({  'START': 0,
  'STOP': 1,
  'DEBUG': 2,
  'STATUS': 3
}); 

var callback = ffi.Callback(bool, [bool, constString], function (sec, data) {
    console.log(sec)
    console.log(data);
  
  });

var libloc = "./Dll1.dll";
  
const ces = ffi.Library(libloc, {
  'Connect': [bool, [constString, constString, 'pointer']],
  'GetCallMethod':[ref.types.void, ['pointer']],
  'Start': [ref.types.void,[ ]],
  'Stop': [ref.types.void,[ ]],
  
});


var maxLength = 200;
var nameBuffer1 = Buffer.alloc(maxLength);
nameBuffer1.fill(0); 
nameBuffer1.write("user", 0, "utf-8"); 


var nameBuffer2 = Buffer.alloc(maxLength);
nameBuffer2.fill(0); 
nameBuffer2.write("password", 0, "utf-8");

ces.Connect(nameBuffer1,nameBuffer2,callback)

function startFunction (e)
{
  // register a new callback each time you call the function in order to use the ipc context
  var callback2 =ffi.Callback(ref.types.void, [int, constString], function (sec, data) {
    console.log(sec);
    // data buffer may need to be converted to a js string using readCString()
    console.log(data);
    e.reply("callback-data", data)
  });

  ces.GetCallMethod(callback2)
  ces.Start()
}

module.exports = {ces, startFunction};
```

You also need to store callback buffers so they don't get garbage collected. The ffi tutorial suggests using `process.on("exit", function() { callback })` but I've found that doesn't work after the electron app is packaged, so I often reference them in a global object.